# Who decides which instructions are to be kept privileged? Is it the hardware manufacturer or the OS developers

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, processor, machine-instruction

I read that there are some privileged instructions in our system that can be executed in kernel mode. But I am unable to understand who make these instructions privileged . Is it the hardware manufacturer that hardwire some harmful instructions as privileged with the help of mode bit or is it the OS designers that make instructions privileged make them work only in privileged mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel vs. user mode, and which instructions aren't allowed in user mode, is part of the ISA.  That's baked in to the hardware.

CPU architects usually have a pretty good idea of what OSes need to do and want to prevent user-space from doing, so these choices at least make privilege levels possible, i.e. make it impossible for user-space to simply take over the machine.

---

But that's not the full picture: on some ISAs, such as x86, later ISA extensions have added control-register flag bits that let the OS choose whether some other instructions are privileged or not.  On x86 that's done for instructions that could leak information about [kernel ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), or make timing side-channels easier.

For example, `rdpmc` (read performance monitor counter) can only be used from user-space if specially enabled by the kernel.  [`rdtsc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtsc) (Read TimeStamp Counter) can be read from user-space by default, but the TSD (TimeStamp Disable) flag in CR4 can restrict its use to priv level 0 (kernel mode).  Stopping user-space from using high-resolution timing is a brute-force way of defending against timing side-channel attacks.

Another x86 extension defends against leaking kernel addresses to make kernel ASLR more secret; CR4.UMIP (User Mode Instruction Prevention) disables instructions like `sgdt` that reads the virtual address of the GDT.  **Those instructions were basically useless for user-space in the first place, and unlike `rdtsc` easily could always have been privileged.**

The Linux Kernel option to enable use of this extension [describes it](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/X86_INTEL_UMIP.html):

> The User Mode Instruction Prevention (UMIP) is a security feature in newer Intel processors. If enabled, a general protection fault is issued if the SGDT, SLDT, SIDT, SMSW or STR instructions are executed in user mode. These instructions unnecessarily expose information about the hardware state.
>
> The vast majority of applications do not use these instructions. For the very few that do, software emulation is provided in specific cases in protected and virtual-8086 modes. Emulated results are dummy.

Setting a new address for the IDT/GDT/LDT (e.g. [`lgdt/lidt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt)) is of course a privileged instruction; those let you take over the machine.  But until kernel ASLR was a thing, there wasn't any reason to stop user-space from reading the address.  It could be in a page that had its page-table entry set to kernel only, preventing user-space from doing anything with that address.  (... until Meltdown made it possible for user-space to use a speculative side-channel to read data from kernel-only pages that were hot in cache.)

Comment: Means privileged instructions are part of ISA. But OS can choose some other instructions to be privileged . Also OS can make some privileged instructions available in user mode if enabled.

Comment: @DivyamBhutani: Only if the ISA gives the OS that choice.  Most instructions are fixed in the ISA as either privileged or not.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks Peter for the help.